# Application Development on WSO2

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-esb

Can I Have any sample Application or full design or Solution blueprint, which is build upon Wso2 with different server (Product) like ESB, DSS, AS, BPS, API Manager, Identity Server and User Interface etc.

So that I can understand how to use all the product to build any application.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can start with reading case studies in wso2 website. For example first two are small and useful. Here is the [link](http://wso2.com/casestudies/) of the wso2 case studies.

Comment: Thanks Reza, already read , Can I have any detail design, Will help alot

Comment: What do you mean by detail design? Do you want to get source code and details like that? What do you want to do?

Comment: No, I dont want source code,Want design so that I can understand the uses of different servers of WSO2

Comment: You have to explore the wso2 website, blog and internet, I think you can not find a document which do that for you.

Comment: can u plz comment on this question ... http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=How+to+create+human+task+and+use+in+BPEL+workflow+using+Developer+Studio

Comment: If my answer helped you, you can accept that as an answer.